# Automatic clicking on java program buttons

Tags: autohotkey, autoit, sikuli, automata

So I need to automate some button clickings on a java program. I tried ahks/autoit's controlclick but it doesn't really work (normal clicks do work, but I require no mouse movement).

I tried to get some information from window detective / window spy, etc. but not much is displayed apart from the window name and ahk_class

Java Ferret shows quite a lot more information though: https://gyazo.com/3539415488ce3e03c90f3532327419f2

How can I trigger one of these "push button" actions? (say "Descendent 19 role")

Comment: just in case you are using windows, try out [tinytask](https://www.tinytask.net/)

Comment: "but I require no mouse movement"... what does this mean?

Comment: @FabriceZaks I think he means he wants to be able to other things while the program is running, and he will need the mouse. Unless there is a non-gui version, I doubt there is a solution. I've looked before

Answer (score 0):

If you can get the X and Y coordinates of the control along with the window name, you could use a mouse click event.

Other than that, you can try using an image search to find the control's X and Y and perform a mouse click.